# C# : How to pause the thread and continue when some event occur?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wait

How can I pause a thread and continue when some event occur?

I want the thread to continue when a button is clicked.
Someone told me that `thread.suspend` is not the proper way to pause a thread.
Is there another solution?

Comment: You could use a [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx)

Comment: @Marlon you could have said that in answer...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx).

An EventWaitHandle blocks until it is signaled. In your case it will be signaled by the button click event.

```
private void MyThread()
{
    // do some stuff

    myWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // this will block until your button is clicked

    // continue thread
}
```

You can signal your wait handle like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myWaitHandle.Set(); // this signals the wait handle and your other thread will continue
}
```

Comment: How to initial EventWaitHandler properly? Is it 
 new EventWaitHandler(false,EventResetMode.AutoReset)

Comment: I do `new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)`. `false` initializes the EventWaitHandle to unsignaled, so it will block.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, suspending a thread is bad practice since you very rarely know *exactly* what a thread is doing at the time. It is more predictable to have the thread run past a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), calling `WaitOne()` each time. This will act as a gate - the controlling thread can call `Reset()` to shut the gate (pausing the thread, but safely), and `Set()` to open the gate (resuming the thread).

For example, you could call `WaitOne` at the start of each loop iteration (or once every `n` iterations if the loop is too tight).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this also

```
private static AutoResetEvent _wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Dosomething();
    }

private void Dosomething()
{
 //Your Loop
 for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
   {
    //Dosomething
    _wait._wait.WaitOne();//Pause the loop until the button was clicked.

   } 
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _wait.Set();
    }
```