# Is there a way to pause a thread indefinitely in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I came to know that Thread.Suspend is not a good way to pause a thread indefinitely. Please let me know if other way to achieve same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this 'System.Threading.EventWaitHandle' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848064/c-sharp-how-to-pause-the-thread-and-continue-when-some-event-occur

Comment: There's no point in suspending a thread forever. Why not just `Abort`-ing it? At least then it won't use up system resources anymore. (Or use the `ThreadPool` for short work items, and you won't have to think about suspending or cleaning up worker threads.)

Comment: There is some really good explaination at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-way-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread

Comment: I am trying to develop a windows form application. Whenever I press pause button, it has to pause until I press resume button. This is what my requirement is.

Comment: The link that I shared (in the comment above) have a sample program as well.

Comment: @Prash Thank you for your help. Actually, I was looking for Vb.Net code in particular. I dont know C#. Its really difficult for me to interpret.

Comment: Understood. Just FYI. Framework being the same irrespective of language (whether C# or VB.NET), it would never be a big concern. Also there are many online converters available online; most famous thing being developer fusion - http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short vb example

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    thrd.IsBackground = True
    thrd.Start()
End Sub

Dim thrd As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf somethread)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'pause and resume
    'first click pauses, second click resumes
    reqpause.Set() 'set event
End Sub

Dim reqpause As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

Private Sub somethread()
    Do
        'simulate work - your code here
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString)
        'end simulate work

        If reqpause.WaitOne(0) Then 'pause requested?
            Debug.WriteLine("t-thrd paused")
            reqpause.WaitOne() 'wait here for continuation
            Debug.WriteLine("t-continue thrd")
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Suspend` and `Resume` is not a good idea.  I am not sure why you want to wait forever, but to wait use an `EventWaitHandle` to wait.

```
private EventWaitHandle handle = new AutoResetEvent();

private void WorkerThread() 
{
    while(true) 
    {
        handle.WaitOne();
    }
}
//Forever is a long time 
public void StopWaitingForever()
{
    handle.Set();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other simpler way is to call `Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`.

Reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).